# Simplest HTML text tag

Tags: asp.net, html

Is there any HTML tag that will wrap my text without changing its style at all? I've tried `<pre>` but that makes it look weird. I need this because I'm trying to include Literal content within a `System.Web.UI.ControlCollection`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`<span>` is what you are looking for.